# How to serialize a complex Map to disk?

Tags: java, caching

I have a simple inmemory cache using `ConcurrentHashMap`. I want that cache to survive restarts. Means, on shutdown I want to write the content to local disk. And on application start, I want to read that local content into the cache map.

I don't need any query-lookups on the local disk cache.

```
//simple key-value store
private final Map<String, Wrapper> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static class Wrapper {
    public List<Transaction> transactions;
    public LocalDateTime timestamp;

    public static class Transaction {
        public String request;
        public String response;
    }
}
```

Question: could you suggest an existing library that can simply write/read such a complex `Map` to a local file?

I thought about serializing the whole content as `json` object, but as I need to read that cache on application restart, performance matters. And that might not be best using json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own methods for serializing and deserializing objects. Notice the use of [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) from [Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library to write to file and read from file.

```
public void serializeAndWriteToFile(Object o) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(o);
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("D:\\Test.txt"), baos.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}

public void readFromFileAndDeserialize() {
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileoByteArray(new File("D:\\Test.txt")));
        ObjectInutStream ois = ne ObjectInutStream(bais);
        Object o = ois.readObject();
        // Type cast o to your object before using it
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: NIce, and one can even make use of `org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils` if already on classpath, for converting from and to bytes. This is probably way better than adding a additional library just for the persistence task (while `mapdb` certainly works too).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [MapDB](https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb).

It does exactly what you want.

Comment: the library works as expected, anyways it's a bit over the top for my simple persistence task.